# javascript code after form submission

Tags: javascript, redirect, form-submit

I tested the following javascript code on a webpage.

```
<form method=POST id="someform" action="http://localhost/somepage.php" >
<input type=hidden name=stuff value="value">
</form>

<script>
document.forms['someform'].submit();
window.location="http://google.com";
</script>
```

The window successfully redirects to google after the form is submitted. I don't understand why. Isn't the control transfered to somepage.php? why is the window.location ... still executed.

Comment: How do you know that it submits? That's what my code looks like and the form doesn't submit. I entered incorrect information into the credit card fields and it should error upon submission, but it redirects to the page I have `window.location` pointing to.

Comment: If you check your debug tools, you "probably" will see that the browser has made two request. One POST or GET (using the form's functionality) and one GET (the "redirect" using javascript). I really don't know how the browser decides what request to serve.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that is called is executed while the page doesn't disappear. The `submit()` call doesn't block the execution, it returns immediately.